# Updated Spring 3.1 project to hibernate4 now getting No Session found for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I had to update my Spring WebFlow project to Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4 do to trying to get maven to work.  It looks like everything is working now but at the part of the project going to do a database read I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
```

I dont know why I did not get this error in hibernate3 but can someone please tell me how to fix this.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>webflow-primefaces-showcase</artifactId>
    <name>JSF 2, Spring Web Flow, and PrimeFaces Showcase</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.5</java-version>
        <springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</springframework-version>
        <springwebflow-version>2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</springwebflow-version>
        <springsecurity-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</springsecurity-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
            <!-- will come with all needed Spring dependencies such as spring-core 
                and spring-beans -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
            <version>${springwebflow-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSF-303 Dependency Injection -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Sun Mojarra JSF 2 runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JSR 303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ********************************************************************** 
            ** HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES ** ********************************************************************** -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For Hibernate Validator -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For Sun Mojarra JSF 2 implementation -->
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For PrimeFaces JSF component library -->

    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>WebFlowTemplate</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

and here is my database.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.uftwf" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">

        <!-- these are C3P0 properties      --> 
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${database.c3p0.acquireIncrement}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${database.c3p0.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${database.c3p0.maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${database.c3p0.maxIdleTime}" />
        <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="${database.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections}" />
        <property name="numHelperThreads" value="${database.c3p0.numHelperThreads}" />
        <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="${database.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout}" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300" />

        <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>org.uftwf.memberinquiry.model.MemberInquiryInformation</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">${format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">25</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">600</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add this to your service:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a lazy loading issue.  Did you enable either the OpenSessionFactoryInViewFilter or OpenSessionFactoryInViewInterceptor?  Any code executing within a transaction should not get this exception, but rendering the view typically happens outside of a transaction necessitating the filter/interceptor.  Hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: I would like to see a full stacktrace and the code for the class throwing the exception

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Session currentSession() throws HibernateException {
    Object value = TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(this.sessionFactory);
    if (value instanceof Session) {
        return (Session) value;
    }
    else if (value instanceof SessionHolder) {
        SessionHolder sessionHolder = (SessionHolder) value;
        Session session = sessionHolder.getSession();
        if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive() &&
                !sessionHolder.isSynchronizedWithTransaction()) {
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(
                    new SpringSessionSynchronization(sessionHolder, this.sessionFactory));
            sessionHolder.setSynchronizedWithTransaction(true);
            // Switch to FlushMode.AUTO, as we have to assume a thread-bound Session
            // with FlushMode.MANUAL, which needs to allow flushing within the transaction.
            FlushMode flushMode = session.getFlushMode();
            if (FlushMode.isManualFlushMode(flushMode) &&
                    !TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly()) {
                session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);
                sessionHolder.setPreviousFlushMode(flushMode);
            }
        }
        return session;
    }
    else if (this.jtaSessionContext != null) {
        Session session = this.jtaSessionContext.currentSession();
        if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive()) {
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new SpringFlushSynchronization(session));
        }
        return session;
    }
    else {
        throw new HibernateException("No Session found for current thread");
    }
}
```

this is the exception thrown from the SpringSessionContext.java, you could debug this code to check wat had happened to the varible value, before we encounter this problem, because we use the hibernate3.SessionHolder then it can not be identified from the instanceof, hope this could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
      </props>
    </property> 
</bean>
```