# No session found for current thread Hibernate4/Spring3

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

Well, it's time for second try - it's been week i'm struggling with this error. Configuration is in XML files instead of annotations. 
This is the stack trace

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/WebAppDB] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread] with root cause
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:941)
    at webapp.dao.DAOUserImpl.getCurrentSession(DAOUserImpl.java:17)
    at webapp.dao.DAOUserImpl.getUser(DAOUserImpl.java:22)
    at webapp.service.ServiceUserImpl.getUser(ServiceUserImpl.java:19)
    at webapp.controller.MainController.showCar(MainController.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:816)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="webapp.service, webapp.dao" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.pass}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="webapp.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
        proxy-target-class="true" />

</beans>
```

service class

```
package webapp.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import webapp.entity.*;
import webapp.dao.*;

@Service
@Transactional
public class ServiceUserImpl implements ServiceUser{

    @Autowired
    private DAOUser daoUser;

    public User getUser() {

    return daoUser.getUser();   
    }
}
```

and DAO class

```
package webapp.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import webapp.entity.User;

@Repository
public class DAOUserImpl implements DAOUser{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory factory;

    private Session getCurrentSession() {
        return factory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public User getUser() {

        return (User) getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User").list().get(0);
    }
}
```

ask for other files if you think error is there
note:
I get the exact same error when i set wrong password or nonexistent user for Mysql which indicates the error might be somewhere here though with this url value in properties file

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

I can get into DB and create schemas

thanks for help in advance

**EDIT**

MainController.java

```
package webapp.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import webapp.entity.User;
import webapp.service.*;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceUser serviceUser;

    @RequestMapping(value={"/index", "/"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showCar(Map<String, User> model) {
        User user = serviceUser.getUser();
        model.put("user", user);

        return new ModelAndView("index", model);

    }

}
```

**EDIT**

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="webapp.controller" />

    <!-- using Spring annotations -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- allows mapping to "/" -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <!-- View resolver - jsp files in WEB-INF/jsp/ -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**EDIT**

logging.log

```
2014-08-06 16:23:26 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:596 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@31dcbf7d: defining beans [serviceUserImpl,DAOUserImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0,dataSource,mySessionFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy

2014-08-06 16:23:28 DEBUG XmlWebApplicationContext:540 - Bean factory for WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7ba7b8d6: defining beans [mainController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@31dcbf7d
```

**EDIT** 
pom.xml

it's a bit bigger then necessary, i used pom.xml from other very similar project (i first encountered this error there) and some dependencies were added in hope of solving this issue according to some other solutions i found on internet

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.judge</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebAppDB</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WebAppDB Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <!-- Build Properties -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- Dependency Versions -->
        <spring.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>
        <bootstrap.version>3.2.0</bootstrap.version>
        <jquery.version>1.9.0</jquery.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Servlet & JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${bootstrap.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache lang utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.efsavage.twitter.bootstrap</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- hibernate 4 and all it takes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.52</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>WebAppDB</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Your stacktrace suggests that your service is not being proxied and, thus, that Spring transaction management is not working as desired. Until you get that fixed, the logic in `SpringSessionContext` (using `TransactionSynchronizationManager`) is not going to work. You could also try plugging in a different `CurrentSessionContext` via the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` Hibernate property (in your `LocalSessionFactoryBean`).

Comment: Can you show code for `webapp.controller.MainController`? It doesn't instantiate `ServiceUserImpl` itself, right?

Comment: Also note that you will probably have to set transaction propagation to REQUIRED for read-only operations, as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12411891/1174467) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9964022/1174467). This is because of [SPR-9020](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9020).

Comment: Post the source code for `MainController`, please.

Comment: @superEb added the MainController file

Comment: Remove `proxy-target-class="true"` from your `<tx:annotation-driven />` element and give it another try.

Comment: Again, your stacktrace is showing that `ServiceUserImpl` is not being proxied. With `proxy-target-class="true"`, it should be using CGLIB to proxy your concrete type, but as @AndreiStefan suggests, you probably don't need that since you're coding to the `ServiceUser` interface. I would try his suggestion and also move the `@Transactional` annotation to the interface, which should result in a JDK proxy (instead of a CGLIB proxy). Could also try moving the annotation to the method as well.

Comment: still nothing - removing proxy-target-class="true" and moving @Transactional to Interface or method didn't help

Comment: Post the xml file you use for the controllers part.

Comment: @AndreiStefan posted spring-servlet.xml , and thanks for trying to help me

Comment: Any differences in stacktrace?

Comment: no, it's exactly the same ...

Comment: It should work. Something's weird somewhere. Enable DEBUG logging in your app and start the app. After it started up, look in your log file for something like this: `Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory` it should be a long line. Post it here. Then look for something like this: `Bean factory for WebApplicationContext for namespace`. Again, it should be a long line. And this should end with something like `parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory`. Post this complete line, as well.

Comment: @AndreiStefan it took me some time to find out what you were asking for but both lines are added to the post

Comment: Does Spring complain at startup if you comment out the transaction related configuration?

Comment: @geoand i deleted Transaction manager bean and <tx:annotation driven> from applicationContext but nothing changed ...

Comment: @TheJudge You mean that the application actually starts? There are no errors reported by Spring during application startup?

Comment: it throws the same No session found exception

Comment: Which Spring version are you using?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Spring 3.2.1.RELEASE

Comment: Do you have spring-tx on your classpath?

Comment: @geoand i got it in pom.xml if that's what you're asking

Comment: Can you please post your pom as well?

Comment: @geoand my pom is posted

Comment: Remove this: `<artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId><version>2.0.6</version>` or adjust the version.

Comment: Definitely get rid of the old Spring dependency!!

Comment: And this is your solution. Just tested it.

Comment: Yeah, I would have expected a NoClassDefFoundError or something related to class loading to spot something like that.

Comment: @AndreiStefan, would you mind posting an answer? Then TheJudge can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `pom.xml` you have a very old version (2.0.6) of Spring for `spring-jdbc` library which, even if it's not really obvious, it seems it interferes somehow with transactional configuration through the `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` class to be set on the `HibernateTransactionManager`.